# ¿Como enviar un correo distinto para diferente formulario en laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel

Necesito enviar un correo para un formulario y otro correo para otro formulario es decir tengo dos formularios en una misma vista, El primer formulario se llama usuario tiene los siguientes campos :

- nombre
- correo
- asunto
- comentario

  cuando el usuario envía el mensaje le va llegar un correo por ejemplo usuario@gmail.com, y tengo el otro formulario que es para empresa tiene los siguientes campos
- nombre
- nit
- correo
- asunto
- comentario

el mensaje deberá llegar al correo empresa@gmail.com, No tengo la menor idea de como hacerlo,¿es posible de agregar dos correo en el .env? ¿hay alguna forma de configurar desde Mail? estoy trabando con laravel, Espero que me entiendan y me ayuden por favor de resolverlo

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el archivo .env solo se agrega el correo que envía los mensajes con su respectiva confuguración, ya si quieres enviar varios correos a destinatarios distintos puedes hacerlo con la clase Mail, *aunque no te recomiendo usar laravel como tal para enviar los correos, deberías hacerlo a través de una API como sendinblue*

En el controller importa la clase Mail

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

y dentro de la función llamada escribe el siguiente código

```
$data = array(
    'clave' => $valor,
);
Mail::send('emails.viewuser', $data, function ($message) {
        $message->from('tucorreo@gmail.com','Registro con exito');
        $message->to('usuario@gmail.com')->subject('Hay un nuevo registro');
});

Mail::send('emails.viewempresa', $data, function ($message) {
        $message->from('tucorreo@gmail.com','Registro con exito');
        $message->to('empresa@gmail.com')->subject('Hay un nuevo registro');
});
```

donde 'emails.view' es la vista que le pasaras en el correo (supongo que es aquí donde va el formulario), $data son los datos que recibe la vista (En caso de que se los pases), tal vez no entendí bien tu pregunta pero básicamente esta es la forma de enviar dos correos distintos